# Teamcity for multiple environments

Tags: android, git, xamarin, continuous-integration, teamcity

i have a xamarin adnroid project and i use teamcity for ci
in our project we set the environment to dev, testing staging etc
based on the set environment url are changed and some other minor changes are made to app.

Right now teamcity build config is to checkout the repo build and create the apk
for whatever environment is set in code
Is there any way that i can create other build config specifically for test or staging environment where i dont need to change the code and it sets the environment as required
These other build will be triggered manually 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

To set environment variables to constant values you can define env.* [TeamCity build parameters](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Build+Parameters).
If you want to calculate the values inside a script and pass the environment variables to the next build step, you can pass them via [TeamCity service message](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameter). There is also [a way](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-12987#comment=27-448099) to "publish" entire current environment to build parameters.